# Translate (from) something to/into something

Tags: prepositions

Dictionaries say that when the word *translate* has its linguistic meaning, we use the preposition *into*:

> He translates English into Russian.

If my understanding is correct, using *to* in the example above is wrong.

But I frequently see *translate* used with the preposition *to*. I suspect that it is correct to use in the pattern *from ... to ...*, e.g.,

> He translates from English to Russian.

Am I right? Is the pattern *translate from ... into ...* also correct?

So, which is correct: "to", "into", "from ... to/into ..."? What sounds more natural for a native speaker?

Comment: You will definitely find the answer [here](https://jakubmarian.com/translate-to-vs-translate-into-in-english/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, by many formal analyses you can use *into*, *from...into*, or *from...to*. There's also the compound adjective pattern *-to-*.

> Translate English into Spanish.
>   Translate this document into Spanish.
>   Translate from Russian into French.
>   Translate from Russian to French.
>   Translate this document from English to Spanish.
>   Can I get a French-to-English translation?

This analysis would say that *English to Spanish*, without a *from*, or *translate this document to Spanish*, would be incorrect. I'm sure that some people do insist that it's 'incorrect' to do that.

Native speakers, in my experience, do it quite frequently. So as well as the above, you will come across:

> Translate Russian to Malagasy.
>   Translate this document to Tamil.

To some it will suggest a poor grasp of English, or a poor education, but it's not at all unusual among native speakers, so it's not a big deal to worry about.

Comment: I wouldn't want to make too much of the point made in @Tasneem's link above (I'm primarily upvoting *your* answer because of the final words), but there is some truth to the distinction being made there (that the preposition in *He translates X **in / into** Y* largely depends on whether X and/or Y are *actual languages*, or *translatable text elements*). Which you *might* wish to mention in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to say it is:

> He translates English into Russian.

The sentense *"He translates from English to Russian."* sounds incorrect to me, however if you wanna use *from*, I guess it is better to say:

> He translate**d** from English to Russian.